# Faster File and memory write

Tags: c

I have a code as defined below, but it is taking too long, I know the reason is there are too many iterations, but is there a solution to make this loop fast, (each loop has to read a float number from a file and write it to the memory) and there are 15874861 numbers.

```
  float  SysMem;
  float fw;
  unsigned long  j;
   for (j = 0 ; j < 15874861 ; j++) 
    {
      fscanf(fp,"%f",&fw); // Read from file
      *((float *) (weights+j*0x04))  = fw; // Write to memory
      // Below lines are just to test, but even just read from file and writing is taking too long.
      SysMem= *((float *) (weights+j*0x04)); // Read back from memory
      if(fw != SysMem) 
         printf("Memory Error\n"); // If read back wrong flag a error
    }
```

Trying to make it faster

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do you know it's too long? Did you time it and do comparisons? Have you tried reading all the floats at once, or in chunks, then iterate??? Or perhaps reading directly into memory and not a variable?? Just ideas.

Comment: I have sat for 45 mins - 1hr 15mins doesn't finish. 
So suspecting if something is either wrong, so with fewer iterations around 100000, I was able to write and finish.

Comment: What is `weights`? Why aren't you using normal array syntax with it? And why are you multiplying the index by 4?

Comment: You should be checking `fscanf()`'s return value for errors, too.

Comment: That code should not take 45 minutes unless something is wrong.

Comment: If you want help with your code rather than hypotheticals, you need to post **[complete code that compiles and runs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**. Also, which platform you're running on, which compiler options you're using, how you're benchmarking, etc. It's quite possible that the problem is in a part of the code that you don't show, or that you're misinterpreting what you're reading.

Comment: It would be also helpful to know how the file you're reading from is. With `fread` you could read a big portion of it into a buffer and then process it (maybe also with multiple threads). In addition if the file is of a particular form and without a special formatting you could read the floats directly the weights array

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not make a difference here, because I/O is the slowest thing that should be happening here, but all those casts don't help performance and may even result in buggy code. A cast tells a compiler “I'm doing something weird here”, and that tends to tell the compiler not to optimize.

For example, on most platforms, the size of `float` is 4 bytes, and it's faster to assign a 4-byte value at an address that's a multiple of 4 than at an arbitrary address. When the compiler sees a variable of type `float` or array of `float`, it will align this variable correctly in memory to be able to use the fast-4-byte-assignment method. When the compiler sees `(float *) (weights+j*0x04)`, it isn't sure whether this is a multiple of 4, so it might generate code that is sure to copy what you expect, but is slower because it copies the individual bytes one by one. (The compiler doesn't have to generate slower code: it can be nasty and assume that `weights` is correctly aligned, and generate code that doesn't copy what you expect if `weights` is not correctly aligned.)

The body of the loop should be just

```
fscanf(fp, "%f", weights[j]);
```

(Assuming that you know that the input file is well-formed, otherwise you need to add error checking.)

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did, for data maneuvering.

```
FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("/media/card/kernel.txt", "r");
  n=0;
  //Read from the file. 
  while(fscanf(fp, "%f", &array[n++])!= EOF);
  // Copy the whole data to memory at the given address
  memcpy(weights, array, sizeof(array) );

// Read back first few and last few values back just to cross check on functionality.
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 10; j++) {
               SysMem= *((float *) (weights+j*0x04));
     printf("Read %f\n", SysMem);
    }

               for (int j = 15874861 ; j > 15874850; j--) {
               SysMem= *((float *) (weights+j*0x04));
     printf("Read %f\n", SysMem);
    }
```

Why I did this?

2 Reasons, I am not running this on a conventional system, it's a custom board.
So I figured out the memory read/writes are costly on time and IO is also slow.
So I just moved the data withing using memcpy.

Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Comment: `SysMem= *((float *) (weights+j*0x04));` sure looks like a potential violation of the [Strict Aliasing Rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), but it is impossible to tell without the rest of your code.